# Only show comments in view where the comment author has a specific role

Tags: views, comments

I am trying to make a Drupal View which only shows the comments of users with a certain role. For example I have a node with content_author who has Role Y. The same user (with Role Y) placed a comment, another user with Role X posted a comment too.

I want to have a view which only displays comments from users with Role X. This does not depend on the user who is logged in, so I cannot use a contextual filter I suppose.

Did anyone manage to do something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to do it.

1. Create a view displaying items of type Node.
2. Create a relationship Comment:User
3. Create a filter User: Roles and require Relationship with User (which was created in 2.
4. Specify the roles

You can style the view (and add fields) as you like.